# Insert code on specific taxonomy archives

Tags: custom-taxonomy, archives

On a woocommerce site, I am trying to insert a piece of code on all category pages. The code I am using is:

```
function my_code() {
    if ( ! is_tax('product_cat') ) return;
    ?>
    <!-- my code goes here-->
    <?php
}
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: Please be more elaborate in your description. Is the contents of this function not showing up? Where is it located? Are you getting PHP errors?

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. I get no errors and nothing shows up. I am adding the code to functions.php file in the currently activated theme folder.

Comment: Are you calling your function inside of `category.php`? Or where are do you have `my_code();` being run?

Comment: im sorry i dont understand the question (im not a developer). The code is being run inside `functions.php`

Comment: A Function is a piece of code to be called later. so above you are defining the function my_code(), but it will never be called unless you put `my_code();` somewhere. In the same folder as functions.php, you should see a category.php file. Put <?php my_code(); ?> where you want the output of this function to appear.

Answer (score 0):

The is_tax() function checks if a custom taxonomy archive page is being displayed. So it will only work in template files such as taxonomy-product_cat.php - unless you create new templates for specific categories in the product_cat taxonomy. For example, if you have a product category called "Toasters" and the slug is "toasters" then the template file would be taxonomy-product_cat-toasters.php, and if that doesn't exist then the taxonomy-product_cat.php template is loaded instead.

See this page for template hierarchy: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display